# Oracle database: Export schema to another machine

Tags: database, oracle

I have a oracle database installed on a server, I want to export one schema to a dump file but this server does not have enough hard drive space. Can I use expdp to export to another machine?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can mount a volume from the second machine then you can export 'locally'. How you do that depends on your operating system etc.

If the second machine already has an Oracle instance you could use its `expdp` with the [`network_link`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#i1011008) parameter. This will export *from* the first machine rather than *to* the second machine, but if the software is available then the end result should be the same and it's just semantics...